# At what point in E.T. do E.T and Elliot begin to 'bond'?

Tags: et-the-extra-terrestrial

I'm rewatching E.T. and noticed something like interesting:

1. Just before the 25 minute mark E.T. purrs and Elliot feels sleepy
2. The next day Elliot is and home and when E.T. begins to eat the car Elliot feels hungry

Does this mark the beginning of their bonding or does it happen later?